# FFMPEG: Fixing frame rate with filter_complex movie filter

Tags: ffmpeg

With some help from @Gyan I came up with the following FFMPEG command which streams 4 videos simultaneously to 4 separate RTMP endpoints, looping the videos infinitely and keeping the audio and video synchronized:

```
ffmpeg \
    -filter_complex \
        "movie=01.mp4:loop=0[v1];[v1]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v1];
         amovie=01.mp4:loop=0[a1];[a1]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1];
         movie=02.mp4:loop=0[v2];[v2]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v2];
         amovie=02.mp4:loop=0[a2];[a2]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a2];
         movie=03.mp4:loop=0[v3];[v3]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v3];
         amovie=03.mp4:loop=0[a3];[a3]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a3];
         movie=04.mp4:loop=0[v4];[v4]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v4];
         amovie=04.mp4:loop=0[a4];[a4]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a4]" \
    -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" \
        -c:a libfdk_aac \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/01 \
    -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" \
        -c:a libfdk_aac \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/02 \
    -map "[v3]" -map "[a3]" \
        -c:a libfdk_aac \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/03 \
    -map "[v4]" -map "[a4]" \
        -c:a libfdk_aac \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/04
```

This is **almost** perfect, except that it's doubling my frame rate:

```
frame=20822 fps= 46 q=32.0 q=34.0 q=29.0 q=32.0 size=   57617kB time=00:14:28.39 bitrate= 543.5kbits/s speed=1.92x
```

Note the `speed=1.92x` bit. This is causing the live stream to play at double speed, as well.

(the original video was approximately 24 fps)

Comment: You've removed the realtime filters from the command I gave?

Comment: I may have misread or mistyped the command you gave. Let me go line by line and see where I messed up

Comment: Looks like I was just missing the `realtime` bit. Not sure if I was still working with an older version of the filters you posted (prior to editing your response to include the whole command) or if I simply failed to copy them. But adding that seems to have fixed it.